# Mold in walnuts

Tags: nuts, soaking

I usually soak and dry walnuts. It tastes much better. Unfortunately, last time, I found that it has developed mold. I soaked them for a night, I dried them for several hours at a very low temperature, and when they were crunchy and seemed dry, I stored them in a crystal container in a cupboard.

- Should I throw them away, or could I recover them somehow?
- What can I improve to avoid the problem next time?

Comment: Your first question is very clear: Mold = discard.

Comment: After drying peppers, I place them in a glass container and look for condensation every day for the next week or so. If I see any inside the jar, I dry them further.  I have no idea if this would be sufficient for nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Put some newspaper in the container and it will absorb the moisture first.